# Late-2013 rMBP able to install & boot Win8 using EFI?

Tags: bootcamp, dual-boot, windows, efi

I've previously installed Win7 (and then upgraded to 8) via Bootcamp, but I've been looking around some forums recently regarding running Win8 natively.

I now have the impression that the latest-gen rMBP will install and boot Win8 using EFI as if it were a native OS. In other words, off an EFI partition and without BIOS emulation.

Can anyone verify this?

I read on a forum (the post was made several weeks previous and the user didn't respond when I posted this question) where a user reported that Bootcamp had installed Win8 on an EFI partition and that the bootup was so much faster.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that if Win8 is installed from an ISO (rather than a Win7 upgrade) then it *will* be installed on a boot-using-EFI partition.